# Regular expressions excluding a particular word

Tags: java, regex

`(1983) The Handsome Hunter Of Africa (HD, 1080p).gif`

I am trying to exclude the keyword `The` with using regular expressions

This regular expression:

`[\w\s-]*([^\d(HD, 1080p\)|\(HD, 720p\)|\(SD, 480p\)|.flv|gif|mkv|mpeg|mpg|mov|)|(])`

Exclude things out of the string and only captures: `The Handsome Hunter Of Africa`

How can I exclude the word **The** from the string and only get: **Handsome Hunter Of Africa**

I only wish to do this in regex.

Comment: what did you tried before?

Comment: Is it just one case or are there many instances like this ? If yes then post some examples.

Comment: That regex doesn't work. The parenthesis before the first `HD` is not escaped, but the real problem is that the entire capture group is a *character class*, and that's just plain wrong. `[^\d(HD, 1080p\)|\(HD, 720p\)|\(SD, 480p\)|.flv|gif|mkv|mpeg|mpg|mov|)|(]` is the same as `[^0-9()|,. DHSefgiklmopv]`

Comment: Why the hassle with capturing? Just use String.replaceAll(pattern,replace_string) for each term you want to replace. e.g. str = str.replaceAll("HD", "X"); .

Answer (score 0):

You could come up with sth. like:

```
\)\s*The\s*([^())]+)
# look for a closing parenthesis and whitespace, The and whitespace
# afterwards, capture everything but parenthesis greedily
# this is saved in a group
# will yield: Handsome Hunter Of Africa
```

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/oU4oM3/2). You'll need to double escape the regex for `Java`.

Comment: @user222222: Did you escape the pattern?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to escape only first "The" in cases like in your example, you can try with:

```
(?<=The|\s)(?:\s+?\w+)+
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zS9jF3/1)